# For i in x : Question about loop for list

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the code I am trying to run, however, I am not sure about how to make it loop for each item in the list. 
Looking for some advice

```
import socket
import time
sock = sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
testinput = input('''Please enter the number corrosponding to the test you would like to carry out 
                1. HTTP Test to Horizon 
    Choice: ''')
if testinput == '1':
    print('You have choosen test 1')
    print('Test port 80 to xsi.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk...')
    for i in ['88.215.60.155', '88.215.60.156', '88.215.60.166', '88.215.60.168']:
        port80result = sock.connect_ex((i, 80))
        if port80result == 0:
            print('Test Successful for ' + i)
```

Running this, I would like to have the socket test, test each IP address in the list.
However I just get the below, and then it ends:

```
    Please enter the number corresponding to the test you would like to carry out                1. HTTP Test to Horizon
    Choice: 1
You have chosen test 1
Test port 80 to xsi.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk...
Test Successful for 88.215.60.155
```

As you can tell, I am still on a steep learning curve

Appreciate anyone's help :)

Comment: How do you know that the loop just ends? You don't print anything for **unsuccessfull** tests, so you don't know if anything else happens.

Comment: You also don't set a timeout for the socket, so connecting to something that never responds would leave the connection call hanging. [Set a timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I have been able to solve this. 
- Added a socket timeout
- Added else: in case the test fails

Updated code below:

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(2)
testinput = input('''Please enter the number corrosponding to the test you would like to carry out 
                1. HTTP Test to Horizon 
    Choice: ''')
if testinput == '1':
    print('You have choosen test 1')
    print('Test port 80 to xsi.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk...')
    for i in ['88.215.60.155', '88.215.60.156', '88.215.60.166', '88.215.60.168']:
        port80result = sock.connect_ex((i, 80))
        socket.timeout(1)
        if port80result == 10061:
            print('Test Successful for ' + i)
        else:
            print(port80result)
```

Comment: Why do you have `if port80result == 10061:`? If the result is 0, the connection succeeded.

Comment: If you run `for i in ['88.215.60.155', '88.215.60.156', '88.215.60.166', '88.215.60.168']:
        port80result = sock.connect_ex((i, 80))` the result returns and prints out 10061

Comment: Actually, I am wrong here. 10061 I believe might be a socket already open. I am not closing the socket